# Need to copy the file from WIndows share path to Linux

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to copy/access the file from windows to Linux using python

1.Mount(Not recommonded)
2.smbclient(getting permission denied)
3.pscp(working fine, But I need to execute the script from Linux, not from Windows)

```
import smbclient
import os
import traceback
try:
    smb = smbclient.SambaClient(server="hyd123", share=r"/harika/1.txt",username='username', password='password',domain='it')
    f = smb.open('file1.txt')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

It's giving the Permission denied

Please suggest me any other approach